# Maintaining view/scroll position in QGraphicsView when swapping images

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview

I'm having trouble with zooming TIFF images loaded into a `QGraphicsView` with `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.

The problem is more maintaining image quality along with having a zoom speed that doesn't make the application choke. To begin with I was just replacing the image with a scaled `QPixmap` - I used `Qt.FastTransformation` while the user was holding down a horizontal slider and then when the slider was released replaced the pixmap again with another scaled pixmap using `Qt.SmoothTransformation`. This gave a nice quality zoomed image but the zooming was jerky after the image size started to increase to larger than its original size; zooming out of the image was fine.

Using QTransform.fromScale() on the QGraphicsView gives much smoother zooming but a lower quality image, even when applying `.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)` to the QGraphicsView.

My latest approach is to combine the two methods and use a `QTransform` on the `QGraphicsView` to have the smooth zooming but when the user releases the slider replace the image in the `QGraphicsView` with a scaled pixmap. This works great, but the position in the view is lost - the user zooms in to one area and because the scaled pixmap is larger the view jumps to another location when the slider is released and the higher quality scaled pixmap replaces the previous image.

I figured that as the width height ratio is the same in both images I could take the percentages of the scrollbars before the image swap and apply the same percentages after the swap and things should work out fine. This works well mostly, but there are still times when the view 'jumps' after swapping the image.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something quite wrong here. Does anybody know of a better way to do this, or can anyone spot something in the code below that could cause this jumping?

This is the code to save/restore the scrollbar location. They are methods of a subclassed `QGraphicsView`:

```
def store_scrollbar_position(self):
    x_max = self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum()
    if x_max:
        x = self.horizontalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        self.scroll_x_percentage = x * (100 / float(x_max))

    y_max = self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
    if y_max:
        y = self.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        self.scroll_y_percentage = y * (100 / float(y_max))


def restore_scrollbar_position(self):
    x_max = self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum()
    if self.scroll_x_percentage and x_max:
        x = x_max * (float(self.scroll_x_percentage) / 100)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(x)

    y_max = self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
    if self.scroll_y_percentage and y_max:
        y = y_max * (float(self.scroll_y_percentage) / 100)
        self.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(y)
```

And here is how I'm doing the scaling. `self.imageFile` is a `QPixmap` and `self.image` is my `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. Again, part of a subclassed `QGraphicsView`. The method is attached to the slider movement with the `highQuality` parameter set to `False`. It is called again on slider release with `highQuality` as `True` to swap the image.

```
def setImageScale(self, scale=None, highQuality=True):
    if self.imageFile.isNull():
        return
    if scale is None:
        scale = self.scale
    self.scale = scale

    self.image.setPixmap(self.imageFile)
    self.scene.setSceneRect(self.image.boundingRect())
    self.image.setPos(0, 0)
    if not highQuality:
        self.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(self.scaleFactor, self.scaleFactor))
        self.store_scrollbar_position()
    else:
        self.image.setPixmap(self.imageFile.scaled(self.scaleFactor * self.imageFile.size(),
                                                   Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.setTransform(self.transform)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(self.image.boundingRect())
        self.image.setPos(0, 0)
        self.restore_scrollbar_position()
    return
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm starting to get quite frustrated with this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works better than the code I first posted. It's still not perfect, but is much improved. Just in case anyone else is trying to solve a similar problem...

When setting the low quality image I call this method added to my QGraphicsView:

```
def get_scroll_state(self):
    """
    Returns a tuple of scene extents percentages. 
    """
    centerPoint = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().width()/2,
                                  self.viewport().height()/2)
    sceneRect = self.sceneRect()
    centerWidth = centerPoint.x() - sceneRect.left()
    centerHeight = centerPoint.y() - sceneRect.top()
    sceneWidth =  sceneRect.width()
    sceneHeight = sceneRect.height()

    sceneWidthPercent = centerWidth / sceneWidth if sceneWidth != 0 else 0
    sceneHeightPercent = centerHeight / sceneHeight if sceneHeight != 0 else 0
    return sceneWidthPercent, sceneHeightPercent
```

This gets stored in `self.scroll_state`. When setting the high quality image I call another function to restore the percentages used in the previous function.

```
def set_scroll_state(self, scroll_state):
    sceneWidthPercent, sceneHeightPercent = scroll_state
    x = (sceneWidthPercent * self.sceneRect().width() +
         self.sceneRect().left())
    y = (sceneHeightPercent * self.sceneRect().height() +
         self.sceneRect().top())
    self.centerOn(x, y)
```

This sets the center position to the same location (percentage-wise) as I was at before swapping the image.